# How to create Post munits mule 4

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mule, anypoint-studio

I need to create an munit of a Post method, but I need to have different Id values, the issue is that the munit only runs successfully once, not sure how to make it work every time I want to run it.

-POST method-
Create an account, thats why I need different emails every time.

I have tried many different ways, but it does not work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Expected and actual outcomes examples would be helpful to clarify.